# How to make the chat bubble animation to work in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I want to do a chat bubble animation. How do I break the animation when one bubble has a longer text and needs to be showed for a longer time.
Is there somekind of a framestop or sth?

view-source:http://www.tlu.ee/~kristo93/svui/yl_p%f5hi_proov.html here's the page/code

Comment: What have you done so far? With some code (jsFiddle) it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: [link](http://sulg.eu/noor/yl_pohi.html) as Fiddle didn't work. I want the woman and the children to talk to eachother and the chatbubbles would be in different places and different size too. Is the KineticJs animation function ok for that?

Comment: I got it to work and stop but how do I change the animation speed. So far it's just ultra fast and stop right away even when I change the framerate

Comment: There are no chatbubbles or `Kinetic.animation` in this link. Am I missing something? If not, please give us a sneak peek at your updated code ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Changed the link. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the `Kinetic.Tween` class in this example here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwqfc/2/)

When you click anywhere on the stage, the rectangle slowly fades in (by changing the `opacity` of the rectangle from `0.0` to `1.0` - fading out works the other way, from `1.0` to `0.0`). In this case you can simply adjust the duration with the `duration` property of the Tween.

To let it fade out you can set a timeout with the setTimeout function:

`setTimeout(function(){var fadeouttween = new Kinetic.Tween(*set opacity from 1.0 to 0.0*);}, *time, after wich the fadeout should start*);`

Comment: As I don't need it to fadeout is there a way for a sprite-changing animation to work slower? Changing the framerate hardly changes it.